# In datatable if I call the method in 'columnDefs' then its not working

Tags: angular, datatables

I am trying to integrate datatable so I added columndefs as per below code, but in columndefs "deleteMember()" method not working.

```
"columnDefs":[
            {
                'targets':7,
                'render': function (data, type, row) {
                    return `<span class="btn-cursor-pointer swal-btn-cancel" member_id="${row.id}" (click)="deleteMember(${row.id})"><i class="i_delete fa fa-trash"></i></span>`;
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: can you post `deleteMember`'s code?

Comment: yes sure but deleteMember method is not trigger on click

Comment: Try with arrow function as in my answer, which datatable you are using?

Comment: jquery datatable "https://datatables.net"

Comment: In general you should avoid using jQuery plugins in Angular, but you can refer this https://www.beyondjava.net/how-to-use-a-javascript-datatable-in-an-angular-application

Answer (score 0):

Your Typescript code is **compiled** : that means when you write `(click)="x()"`, once the CLI does it's job, it will be rendered as valid JS, such as `onclick="x()"`.

In your case, you are giving a string : this is done *once the code is compiled*. This means it will never work.

To do that, you will have to create windows functions, bound to your own component functions, and bind the click events on it.

Answer (score 0):

Its a jquery datatable so not working angular code

So I done this using jquery now its working

```
var self = this;
    jQuery('#membersDatatable').on('click', '.delete-member', ($event) =>{
        var member_id = $($event.currentTarget).attr('member_id');
        self.deleteMember(member_id);
    })
```